# My NSString object is not being updated until I leave my main viewController and go back?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsmutablearray, viewdidappear

I have been trying to figure this out for the last couple of hours and still cannot figure it out or find anything related that might help me out.

I have a method `showFriendRequestData` and this method makes a server call to get a JSON response. I take my data that I get back and store it into an `NSMutableArray`. I than make an NSString object and store the total amount of items in the array to a string value.

I then add the value to a UILabel object and try to display it. I have tried calling this method `showFriendRequestData` in my `viewDidAppear` method like this.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self showFriendRequestData];
}
```

But ONLY when I leave the mainViewController and go BACK does the label update..... Make no sense. Am I calling this method I made in the wrong place?? Any help or guidance would be great. I want the label to update the moment I login into my main view controller.

Comment: How are we supposed to help you without knowing what showFriendRequestData does?

Comment: Which NSString? And how does it relate to the UI?

Comment: Got it figured out, thanks gothic dev! I just added the same thing for ViewWillAppear and it worked just like I wanted it to. @rdelmar I do apologize for not putting more info on that method, it just had a few server things I did not want to reveal.

Comment: Shorten, edit and rename that post so that the question and the response do match.

Answer (score 1):

You must invoke `[super viewDidAppear:animated];`

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self showFriendRequestData];
}
```

Setting your data too late?

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // ...
}
```

See [guidelines-for-viewwillappear-viewdidappear-viewwilldisappear-viewdiddisappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386333/guidelines-for-viewwillappear-viewdidappear-viewwilldisappear-viewdiddisappea) for complete instructions.

Comment: I tried that and it still did not work but after doing the same thing for the viewWillAppear it worked, thanks!